# Error : "ARTShape" was not found in the UIManager - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I just upgraded my expo SDK to the last version so I faced some issue about some screens where the **react-native-pie-chart** & **react-native-pie** doesn't work I google it but I didnt found the solution for those who suggest to link the react-native-community/art that's not working in **Expo**.May someone suide me to solve it please

Error:

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ARTShape" was not found
> in the UIManager.
>
> This error is located at:
> in ARTShape (created by Shape)
> in Shape (at Pie.tsx:42)
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I notice that those libraries are not working in this version so I tried to find a solution and I found it won't work on Android because it needs to be link as you are using the expo so it's not possible.

*Solution proposed :* You can eject the project than can run it.
And that's not working for me because I'm using some features of expo so I tried to install

`expo install react-native-svg-charts`

and worked 100% for me. I hope that's help

Comment: i had to use another package, react-native-qrcode-svg to achieve my aim too